# How to convert MySQL timestamp to d-m-yyyy

Tags: php, mysqli, timestamp

```
$newTime = "TIME_FORMAT(date, '%e-%M-Y') AS date";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, text, $newTime FROM gastenboek");
```

This is some information selecten from the database, i want to convert the sql timestamp to php days - months - years (22-11-2013).

The query works fine but date = NULL

it seems that my query is wrong, because when i do SELECT * FROM gastenboek it all works fine.

Error code: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

I already googled the problem but i can't find the solution.

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advanced!

Greetings from Holland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `DATE_FORMAT` instead of `TIME_FORMAT`. And I think your format string needs to be tweaked. Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e-%c-%Y') AS date
```

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) for `TIME_FORMAT` say:

> This is used like the DATE_FORMAT() function, but the format string may contain format specifiers **only for hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds**. Other specifiers **produce a NULL value** or 0.

Answer (score 0):

you have a , (comma) right before FROM  (after $newtime)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, but still the date output = NULL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mysql timestamp will be equivalent as NOW() function output, you can use the following method:

```
SELECT concat(day(now()),"-",month(now()),"-",year(now())) as date
```

Not the most efficient approach but will get the job done.